# Xcode makes invalid Distribution profiles on member center

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been trying for a couple of days to get Active my Provision Profiles for distribution. The problem is that every time that I refresh provision profiles from Xcode it makes invalid distribution profiles on Member Center. I've tried deleting and recreating the profiles, downloading and reinstalling them manually. I've also tried by deleting the profiles from ~/Library/MobileDecice/Provisioning Profiles with no luck.

It's also important to mention that I had Xcode-beta6 installed but I removed it from the system and got same result.

Do you have any ideas what may be wrong? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I had the same issues the last few days. There's nothing to do but report it to Apple. What worked for me was downloading the provisioning profiles from the website and dragging them onto Xcode.

Comment: I'm afraid that I've done that about two hundred times? ;) with no luck at all. Nevertheless thank you for your comment I guess that I'll have to report the issue to Apple :(. By the way, could it have something to do with next Apple's event on 9th, September?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update to Xcode6-GM and problem disappeared, seems that had to do with Beta versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it really took me a while to configure it.

Be sure to follow these steps:

1. Go to LaunchPad and search KeyChain, and open it
2. Follow the steps on the picture below

   [image]
3. Certificate Assistant will appear, and enter your email, Name Surname leave the third field empty and be sure that you select Saved to Disk.
4. Click Continue and this will generate a certificate, save it for example to Desktop or a place that you remember because you will be needing this. (Its a .certSigningRequest file)

   [image]
5. Close KeyChain and go to developer.apple.com, login and go to Member Center
6. Click to Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles.
7. On iOS Apps choose Certificates
8. Select 'All' on Certificates
9. Click the + button to Add a New Certificate
10. If you don't have a Development Certificate create it, then you need an App Store Certificate to Distribute Applications. (We are providing an example for Distribution, but it is the same thing also for Development)

    [image]
11. Click to Continue, and when I requires you to enter a file, browse and find your .certSigningRequest file which was generated from KeyChain
12. Now that your certificate is created, Download it but don't install it yet.
13. Now we suppose you already have an Application on Store which is also at App IDs (Identifier Panel), if you don't create one.
14. Now go to provisioning profiles
15. Click + to add New Provisioning Profiles (Remember you can use just one Provisioning Profile for different MACs)

    [image]
16. Choose App Store to be able to submit apps to App Store
17. Select your AppID, (Check step 13 if you don't have one)
18. Select Certificate that you created on the previous steps
19. Download the recent version of the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility)
20. Drag your provisioning profile on it and everything should be OK
21. If you are still having trouble. Delete all provisioning profiles from KeyChain and everything from Apple Developer except your added ones. Now everything should be returned to normal.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks for your reply but it doesn't work I have the same issue. I cannot see the reason because the profile is invalid.

Comment: @SantiFdezMunoz did you check if you accidentally removed your account from Xcode. To check at Menu Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts and add your apple id.

Comment: Thank you @Erid for the suggestion, but unfortunatelly I already tried that approach before asking here. I think that it could have to do with a dirty uninstallation of XCode6-Beta 6. I'll wait until Xcode6 reléase and check again :). Thanks anyway for your comment.