# No Provisiong Profile and no code signing identities found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am stuck with serious problem, i did everything but i cannot make build, i face this issue No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did pressing "Fix Issue" do?

Comment: it select provisiong profile none, and archive sucessfully

Comment: If you go into the target build settings, does your provisioning profile show in the `Code Signing Identity` drop downs? If not try dragging it into Xcode.

Comment: Have you checked guideline for creating profile and certificate for adhoc build? 

There might be an issue with profile. Your provisional profile which you set in build setting might not signed with certificate which you have in keychain.

Or your device id is not added in that profile.

Comment: Remove every license related to the **Provisioning Profile**, and try this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567481/xcode-makes-invalid-distribution-profiles-on-member-center/25569735#25569735

Comment: i updated my question, i cannot export it

Comment: it shows me drop down ,, and i can select provisiong profile ,,,yes device id is added in it