# Apple Development Certificate issues

Tags: ios, certificate

I have managed to get my Development and Distribution certificates in something of a mess (started with separate one for each App and more)
I'd like to start again with just one, generic, cert for each of Development and Distribution.
There are lots of tutorials on re-creating deleted or expired certificates but I can't find any confirmation that I can delete everything and start afresh (and, presumably, then use the new cert for new apps and/or updates to old ones?)

Has anyone actually gone through the steps of cancelling/deleting all Apple certificates and starting again? If so, any advice on steps and things to avoid will be appreciated.
thanks

Many thanks for the suggestions which I have now implemented.

I do now have just one each Development and Distribution certificate (although Xcode re-created the dozens of provisioning profiles I was trying to get rid of - I guess I will have to live with that long list for ever...).

An interesting result is the error message I received when I uploaded a new version of an App:

"Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['xxxxxxxxx.com.jeffmaynard.eurosceptic'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['yyyyyyyyyy.com.jeffmaynard.eurosceptic']. This will result in a loss of keychain access."

Although the App has gone to review I am not sure of the consequences of this error message which I assume results from the certificate updates?

Comment: Check out this answer for your problem with Keychain Loss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792236/application-identifier-entitlement-value-has-changed/23877303#23877303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear your certificates in 2 places:

## Keychain

Follow these steps to navigate and clear the certificates:

1. Open LaunchPad
2. Keychain Access
3. Select your Keychain
4. Select My Certificates

Now here you need to delete every certificate that starts with **iPhone Developer** or **iPhone Distribution**

## Apple Developers Members Center

1. Login to Apple Developers
2. Go to Member Center
3. Click: Manage your certificates, App IDs, devices, and provisioning profiles
4. You have 2 tabs to interact Certificates and Provisioning Profiles

Remove all of them (Remember you can't delete those Provisioning Profiles, that are already in App Store).

Then you need to create it from the beginning: Follow my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567481/xcode-makes-invalid-distribution-profi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bles-on-member-center/25569735#25569735)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions which I have now implemented. I do now have just one each Development and Distribution certificate (although Xcode re-created the dozens of provisioning profiles I was trying to get  rid of).

Comment: Click on Xcode Menu -> Preferences -> Accounts and remove them all, and add the one you need. If this question helped you, Ill be glad if you give me a vote up and accept this answer :)